# Detectar cambios realizados en controles WindowsForms, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Necesito detectar los cambios que se realizaron en el formulario, ya sea en `TextBox`, `Datagridview` u otros controles.

> Aquí dejo un [pequeño ejemplo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SGe4-cL61YxlIijIC99R8zTVrVM6Tw3-/view?usp=sharing) como código de prueba (Enlace GoogleDrive) `IdentificarCambios.zip`
>
> Esto me **Funciona Perfectamente** , pero considero que debe existir un método mas óptimo y práctico. se que el `Dataset` contiene un método llamado `HasChanges` pero NO se como usarlo para obtener el resultado que deseo.

Aquí comienzo la explicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui vemos este formulario como se puede observar el `Boton Salvar` esta deshabilitado , porque son los datos originales cargados inicialmente. Si realizo algún cambio en alguna de estas celdas: `Hora Entrada`, `Hora Salida`, `Cantidad` luego que se dispare el evento `CellEndEdit` se invoca una `Función` llamada `verificar_cambios` la cual funciona de la siguiente manera:

> Inicialmente cuando se cargan los datos tengo dos `dataset` de los cuales el **dataset original lo copio al segundo dataset** de modo que contengan los mismos datos, entonces en la funcion `Verificar_cambios` realizo la validación de si el valor que se encuentra en el `dataset original` es el mismo que se encuentra en el `otro dataset` si es el mismo el `botón Salvar` no se habilita, de lo contrario el `botón Salvar` se habilita.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar en la segunda imagen he cambiado el valor de la `celda` de `5` a `10` se invocó la función y habilitó el `botón salvar`. **Pero** si el `usuario` vuelve a colocar su valor a `5` la funcion nuevamente `deshabilita` el `botón salvar`. no se como lograr eso con `HasChanges`.

**EDITADA**

**Fragmento del Código:**

Cuando carga los datos:

```
dataset_cambios = dataset_datos.Copy();
```

**Función Verificar Cambios:**

```
private void verificar_cambios()
{
     string cantidad = string.Empty cantidad_cambios = string.Empty;
     for (int fila = 0; fila < dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows.Count; fila++)
     {
          if (dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[fila]["cantidad"].ToString() == string.Empty)
              cantidad = string.Empty;
          else
              cantidad = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[fila]["cantidad"].ToString().Trim();

          if (dataset_cambios.Tables[0].Rows[fila]["cantidad"].ToString() == string.Empty)
              cantidad_cambios = string.Empty;
          else
          cantidad_cambios = dataset_cambios.Tables[0].Rows[fila]["cantidad"].ToString().Trim();

         //Verificando si la variable del dataset original es diferente a la del dataset guardado inicialmente. 
         if (cantidad.Equals(cantidad_cambios))
         {
             //No hay cambios
             btn_salvar.Enabled = false;
         }
         else
         {
             //Si hay cambios
             btn_salvar.Enabled = true;
             break;
         }
     }
  }
```

Entonces, **¿Cómo optimizo este método, o crear uno más eficiente?**

**Nota:** No he colocado todo el [código del proyecto](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SGe4-cL61YxlIijIC99R8zTVrVM6Tw3-/view?usp=sharing) para no agrandar tanto la publicación.

> Visual Studio 2010 y .NET Framework 4

Comment: Deberias guardar un set de datos originales y siempre comparar contra ellos. pero eso implicaria tener todos los datos duplicados. Ponete a pensar si eso realmente vale la pena.

Comment: Pero eso que dices es exactamente lo que estoy haciendo cuando hago esto: **dataset_cambios = dataset_datos.Copy();** el dataset datos es el original y el que dice cambios contiene también los mismos datos para luego compararlos, **Es por ello que no veo que sea un método optimo** deseo cambiar eso o mejorarlo no se como hacerlo.

Comment: porque decis que no es optimo entonces. optimo en que sentido?

Comment: Tambien podrias utilizar la transaccionalidad de los datasets, recuerda que puedes hacer un commit o un rollback en datasets

Comment: @gbianchi porque de ese modo si hago un cambio en una sola celda, de todos modos el método verifica en **todas las celdas** eso haría que con una gran cantidad de datos y controles sea mas lento no?

Comment: y cual es tu problema con haschange?

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver no se como se aplica lo que dices en este caso de los cambios, porque no estoy hablando de cuando salvo los datos a la BD para usar Commit o rollback para devolver la transacción, eso lo haría al momento de enviar los datos a la BD pero aqui lo que planteo es otro tema

Comment: @gbianchi si no me equivoco **HasChanges** devuelve un true o false si se realizaron cambios eso esta Bien pero si el usuario vuelve y coloca el dato tal y como estaba antes de cambiarlo el HasChanges de todos modos continua siendo verdadero y no quiero eso asi

Comment: Pensemos si es un **Datadridview** que contiene al menos 25 columnas editables, tendría que crear 4 sentencias **if** para cada columna tal como esta el método actualmente, por eso considero que debe haber una manera más adecuada

Comment: un iterador por las columnas? un metodo generico de comparacion? tiene sentido esto? cual es la probablidad de que trate de grabar despues de volver atras un dato? cual es el costo de volver a grabar? no siempre algo que parece que soluciona algo realmente lo soluciona

Comment: @gbianchi `Cual es la probabilidad de que trate de grabar despues de volver atrás un dato?` si por ejemplo el usuario edita una celda por error y vuelve a colocar su valor original. Volver a grabar de forma innecesaria consumiría recursos del equipo supongo.

Comment: Consumir recursos del equipo que quiere decir? debes tomar en consideracion que duplicar todo tu set de datos tambien consume datos del equipo. y comparar 25 campos tambien consume ciclos de tu sistema. Por lo tanto, que quiere decir consumir recursos del equipo?

Comment: Eso mismo, consumir mas recursos de lo que ya esta consumiendo el método, por eso quisiera un método en que no tenga que duplicar los datos si es que existe alguno

Comment: No. No existe. Salvo que vuelvas a comparar todo contra la BD en cada vuelta, otra locura. y vuelvo a preguntar.. de que tipo de recursos hablas?

Comment: No comprarlo con la BD es una locura mayor.  Con `Recursos` me refiero a tiempo se ejecución, memoria etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria mucho mas fácil si trabajas con colecciones de objectos y Linq, incluso mejor con entity framework y changetracker, pero para el ejemplo que has pasado esta es una solución:

Añade AcceptChanges en el método generar_datos (se obtendrán los cambios a partir de este momento)

```
dataset_datos.AcceptChanges();

myDataGrid.DataSource = dataset_datos.Tables[0];
```

Para obtener los cambios en el método verificar_cambios

```
  if (dataset_datos.HasChanges())
  {
     var tempDataSet = dataset_datos.Tables[0].GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
     var tempDataSet1 = dataset_datos.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
     var tempDataSet2 = dataset_datos.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
     var tempDataSet3 = dataset_datos.GetChanges(DataRowState.Unchanged);  
  }
```

Asi recuperamos los valores actuales y los originales

```
DataRow[] ModifiedCurrentRows = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent);

foreach (DataRow Row in ModifiedCurrentRows)
{
        foreach (DataColumn catCol in dataset_datos.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
                 Console.Write(Row[catCol, DataRowVersion.Original] + "\t");
                 Console.Write(Row[catCol, DataRowVersion.Current] + "\t");

        }
         Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Con este método `var tempDataSet = dataset_datos.Tables[0].GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);`, cuando realizo un cambio en una celda, no identifica el cambio tan pronto ocurre, me explico si modifico 2 `celdas` y luego contabilizo la cantidad de filas que tiene este `tempDataSet ` que serán las modificadas, solo me devuelve `1` si modifico 3 celdas devuelve `2`, es decir que la ultima modificación se lanza cuando se realiza otra. Y otra cosa, **¿cómo puedo obtener el valor anterior  de la `celda` al que se modificó?**

Comment: Lo que tengo entendido es que antes de llamar a `AcceptChanges` el método del `dataset` no se actualizará con nuevos valores, por lo que este antiguo valor debería estar allí pero, **¿cómo recuperarlo?** he visto algo como esto: `dataRow.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Proposed`

Comment: asi aparecen los valores actuales y originales , DataRow[] ModifiedCurrentRows = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent);  foreach (DataRow Row in ModifiedCurrentRows)
                {                    foreach (DataColumn catCol in dataset_datos.Tables[0].Columns)
                    {
                        Console.Write(Row[catCol, DataRowVersion.Original] + "\t");
                        Console.Write(Row[catCol, DataRowVersion.Current] + "\t");                   
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

Comment: Perfecto, que significa cuando pasas `Select(null, null,...`  es decir, por qué los dos primeros parámetros `null`?

Comment: Filtro y orden , https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Listo, gracias!